# jade-bootstrap installation file not found

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm trying to use jade-bootstrap but I'm obviously missing a step.

Per the [jade-bootstrap installation instructions](https://rajasegar.github.io/JADE-Bootstrap/getting-started.html):

- I ran 'npm install jade-bootstrap' and see the package within node_modules.
- I extended my index.jade with _boostrap.

my code:

```
extends _bootstrap

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
```

But I receive this error:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/myproject/views/_bootstrap.jade'

What am I missing here?  I don't have to copy the bootstrap .jade files into my project do I?

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of [this example](https://github.com/rajasegar/jadebootstrap-seed/blob/master/views/index.jade) you actually need the relative path to `_bootstrap.jade` which should be something like:

```
extends ../node_modules/jade-bootstrap/_bootstrap.jade
```

Answer (score 0):

Confusingly jade bootstrap now uses pug (the new name for jade).

If you are using jade with express:

so it may be possible that your app's (especially if it is generated by express-generator) view engine is set to jade and not pug.

`app.set('view engine', 'pug');`

And then in your pug file

`extends ../node_modules/jade-bootstrap/_bootstrap`